# ruby cat shell similar

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have used shell in the past. I am converting a shell program to ruby. I have the following command

```
cmd="cat -n " + infile + " | grep '127.0.0.1 '" + site
f = %x[#{cmd}]
```

The shell cat command returns the line I am looking for and the line number. I would like to be able to do something similar in ruby without using shell. May need to port this program to windows. I can use the grep function in ruby but how do I return the line number without having to loop through a million lines in a file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little ruby function that'll do what you're asking for.  You do have to loop through each line, but `grep` was doing that too - you just didn't have to do it yourself.  Fortunately, ruby makes looping easy:

```
def mygrep(filename, regex)
    result = []
    File.open(filename) do |f|
        f.each_with_index do |l, i|
            result << [i, l] if regex =~ l
        end
    end
    return result
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Condense it more : `File.open(f).each_with_index do |l,i| ... end`

Comment: @KassymDorsel - If you give a block to [File.open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open), the file automatically closes when the block returns.  I'll almost always do that, as I think it's more convenient.